# Android - try to connect to Dropbox API version 2

Tags: java, android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm try to connect to Dropbox api version 2 via Android Studio but I get this exception:

```
04-27 23:49:33.356 6482-6482/com.example.user.trackyournevi 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                              
Process: com.example.user.trackyournevi, PID: 6482                                                                                      
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.trackyournevi/com.example.user.trackyournevi.Drop
boxActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find 
explicit activity class 
{com.example.user.trackyournevi/com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

My Dropbox Activity:

```
    public class DropboxActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    private LinearLayout container;
    private boolean isUserLoggedIn;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnUpload;
    private Button btnDownload;

    private DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession> mDropboxApi;

    private final static String DROPBOX_FILE_DIR = "/TrackYourNevi/";
    private static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 20;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_dropbox);

       loggedIn(false);
       //callback method
       initializeSession();
    }

    private void initializeSession() {
    //store app key and secret key
    AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(getResources().getString(R.string.DROPBOX_APP_KEY),
            getResources().getString(R.string.DROPBOX_APP_SECRET));
    AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys);
    //Pass app key pair to new DropboxApi object
    mDropboxApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
    //start session
    mDropboxApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(DropboxActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mDropboxApi.getSession().authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            // Required to complete auth, sets the access token on the session
            mDropboxApi.getSession().finishAuthentication();
            String accessToken = mDropboxApi.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
            loggedIn(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.dxbLoginButton:
            if(isUserLoggedIn) {
                mDropboxApi.getSession().unlink();
                loggedIn(false);
            } else
                mDropboxApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(DropboxActivity.this);
            break;
        case R.id.dxbUploadButton:
            //invoke the image gallery using an implict intent
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            //Where do we want to find the data
            File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            String pictureDitrectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.image_folder_name);
            //Get URI representation
            Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDitrectoryPath);
            //Set the data and type. get all images from jpg type
            photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/jpg");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);
            break;
        case R.id.dxbDownloanButton:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

And my manifiest.xml contains the following data:

```
    activity android:name=".DropboxActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"
    intent-filter
        data android:scheme="db-key"
        action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"
        category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    intent-filter
    activity
```

It looks like I defined everything as I saw in other tutorials but still it's not working.
Is someone see the problem and can help me?

Comment: What Dropbox library do you have installed? If you're trying to use Dropbox API v2 (which you should), you should use the [API v2 Java SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java). The code you're trying to use appears to be for the [API v1 Android Core SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/start/android). There's [an example of using the API v2 SDK in Android here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android).

Comment: Where did you see the API v2 Java SDK? I keep moving to GitHub for a sample code without any SDK

Comment: Here's the link for the API v2 Java SDK (also linked in my previous comment): https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java